# CLANG version 15, indentation issue

Tags: clang-format

I have enabled ***IndentPPDirectives*** to ***BeforeHash***, and I am getting the correct expected behavior in which the following:

```
#if FOO
  #if BAR
    #include <foo>
  #endif
#endif
```

However, the case is that I would like to have something like that:

```
#if FOO
  #if BAR
    #include <foo>
    code();
    while()
    {
      //Do something
    }
  #endif
#endif
```

instead of:

```
#if FOO
  #if BAR
    #include <foo>
code();
while()
{
  //Do something
}
  #endif
#endif
```

Is it possible to manage that by clang-format version 15 or even other versions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's impossible. Preprocessor directive alignment doesn't affect the code alignment.